# Formhelper to add a line Break in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

The Form helper in cakephp

```
  echo $form->input('Firstname', array('class'=>'test','name'=>'Firstname','type'=>'text'));
```

generates me like the following

```
   <div class="input text">
      <label for="Firstname">Frrstname</label>
      <input type="text" id="Firstname" value="" class="test" name="Firstname"/>
   </div>
```

is it possible to add a Break between label and input within the DIV .. If so how .. please suggest

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not adding the break.

Just use css:

label{display:block}

would achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $form->input('Firstname', array( 'between'=>'<br />','class'=>'test','name'=>'Firstname','type'=>'text'));
```